# Mobile Safari doesn't trigger "orientationchange"—how to debug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

I have a website (`http://7db.9ed.myftpupload.com/`) that I would like to display content tailored to orientation. When in landscape mode, it should display a wide slideshow, when in portrait it should switch to a thin slideshow.

I'm attempting to use the "orientationchange" event as Apple specifies in the Safari Web Content Guide.

`jQuery( document ).ready( 
    function() { 
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
            console.log("the orientation of the device is now " + screen.orientation.angle);
        placeSlideshow();
    }, false);
});`

This works without a hitch in Chrome's iOS simulator. But, in both the OSX hardware simulator and on a live iOS device, nothing happens on orientation change. It's not the `placeSlideshow` function—Safari isn't triggering an orientation change at all.

At a loss to troubleshoot this—where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was actually the `console.log` call I had added in. Safari does not recognize the property `screen.orientation.angle,` and for a reason unknown to me, this call managed to torpedo the entire callback.

I removed the log call and everything works normally.

Comment: At least on iOS 12.4.4, on iPhone 6, the screen.orientation object is not defined.  It is defined in Chrome Dev Tools on Windows, when you click the change orientation button, but not on an actual iPhone.  That's why your console log call fails.